# Class prefixes in project with both objective-c and swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm aware that we no longer need to prefix class names in swift. But I'm working on a project containing both swift and Objective-c. 
Should I prefix the swift class names of keep them the "swift way"?

Comment: BTW: There is no need to prefix application class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go ahead and keep it the Swift way. If you're worried about name-clashes and adding a prefix, you can change the Objective-C class name by adding `@objc(...)` before the class declaration.

E.g.

```
@objc(XXMyClass) class MyClass: ... {
    ...
}
```